# How to access RichTextBox.Select() method while referring to it as a "Control"

Tags: c#

### Trying to access RichTextBox methods when C# recognizes it as a control!

I'm trying to access RichTextBox class methods when the RichTextBox is recognized as a member of the Control class. I've currently tried:

```
private void new_Page()
{
    TabControl tbcPages = TabControl();
    TabPage first = new TabPage();
    RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
    rtb.Text = "Why C#? WHY?!";
    first.Add(rtb);
    tbcPages.Add(first);
}
private void TextSelectionAtSomePoint()
{
    int selectionStart = 0;
    int selectionEnd = 6;
    tbcPages.Controls[0].Controls[0].Select(selectionStart,selectionEnd);
    //This line above does not work as the Select method for the Control class is completely different.
}
```

But I've also tried this (same new_Page method).

```
private void TextSelectionAtSomePoint()
{
    int selectionStart = 0;
    int selectionEnd = 6;
    RichTextBox newrtb = (RichTextBox)tbcPages.Controls[0].Controls[0];
    newrtb.Select(selectionStart,selectionEnd);
    tbcPages.Controls[0].Controls.RemoveAt(0);
    tbcPages.Controls[0].Controls.Add(newrtb);
}
```

Comment: You are going to get lost in your own code if you keep coding like this: `tbcPages.Controls[0].Controls[0]`  Why are you trying to remove the control just to add it back in?

Comment: You have to upcast the `Control` reference to a reference of a derived type (`RichTextBox` in this case) and then you will be able to invoke the methods of the derived class.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile by the way.  Show us the real code you are using.

Comment: This is essentially my code, I'm merely saving time by removing a huge ton of it! The structure and method of my code above is more or less the same as this.

Comment: Converting this into a [mcve] would make the question much better. It doesn't need to be your actual code - but it needs to be *representative* of your original code in all important aspects, with all the unimportant aspects completely removed.

Comment: @JonSkeet And it is. to disagree would be to assume that you know my actual code better than I do.

Comment: It's not complete. I can tell that without seeing any of your actual code - I can tell that it's incomplete because I can't copy it, paste it into a new text file, and compile it. It doesn't contain a class declaration, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet It doesn't need to be compilable, you can see what I'm trying to do and I explained the problem with the code. I think anyone with half a brain could transplant this into a generic project and compile it anyway.

Comment: Yes, I could - with effort. And anyone reading it later could put effort into understanding everything too. Or *one person* (you) could put effort into making the question as good as possible. I know which approach I think is better, and the Stack Overflow community tends to agree, in my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void TextSelectionAtSomePoint() {
    int selectionStart = 0;
    int selectionEnd = 6;
    var temp = tbcPages.Controls[0].Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
    if(temp != null)
        temp.Select(selectionStart,selectionEnd);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As @JonSkeet said in comments, seems the OP expects a `RichTextBox` here; so if it's not, it really should throw an `InvalidCastException`, not just ignore it. So, I update the answer to this:

```
private void TextSelectionAtSomePoint() {
    int selectionStart = 0;
    int selectionEnd = 6;
    ((RichTextBox)tbcPages.Controls[0].Controls[0])
        .Select(selectionStart,selectionEnd);
}
```

Comment: So would "temp" directly influence RichTextBox I have in place, or would it simply influence a "copy" as that is what "var temp = (RichTextBox)tbc.Controls[0].Controls[0];" does!

Comment: The `temp` is a reference to your main `RichTextBox` and any changes to `temp` will affect to the main `RichTextBox`. The `as` keyword is a cost operation. While you are accessing to `RichTextBox` by indexing `tbcPages` and it's a bad, bad way to do this stuffs, so it's better to safe costing objects rather that direct cost. I mean, it's better to use `as` keyword, instead of `(RichTextBox)obj` pattern

Comment: I would generally prefer a cast over using `as` here, as it would indicate a bug which should be found and fixed, not ignored. The `as` operator should only be used (IMO) when it's entirely legitimate for the target *not* to be an instance of the relevant type. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions/

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, it's my pleasure having your comment :) Did you mean: `if (control is RichTextBox) ((RichTextBox)control).Select()`? Would you show a snippet please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry: No, I mean an unconditional cast. It looks like the OP really, really expects `tbcPages.Controls[0].Controls[0]` to be a `RichTextBox`. If it's not, an `InvalidCastException` is probably the best way of being alerted to that assumption being invalid - rather than just ignoring the request to select text.

Comment: OK I got it. Updating the answer. Thanks again.